# AngularFire2 call back for setting values

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 for my angular 2 project.

Inside my forms.service.ts, I have the following to save to firebase

```
saveToFirebase(bug: MyBugs) {

    const bugRef = this.af.database.object('/bugs');

    bugRef.set(bug)
}
```

And inside my app.component.ts, I have

```
this.formsService.saveToFirebase(bug);
```

I can see that my firebase was able to save the data. However, I'd like to have some sort of call back for the status of the request (Success, failed, timeout?) such that I can display some sort of activity indicator during the process. I'd like to do this inside my app.component files where I call saveToFirebase()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`set` returns a promise](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/src/database/firebase_object_observable.ts#L18-L23), so if you return said promise from your service method:

```
saveToFirebase(bug: MyBugs): Promise<void> {
    const bugsObject = this.af.database.object('/bugs');
    return bugsObject.set(bug);
}
```

it can be called like this:

```
this.formsService
  .saveToFirebase(bug)
  .then(() => console.log('done!'))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Given that the database path you've used is named `bugs` and that you appear to be adding a single bug, it's likely that [`list`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md) and [`push`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#api-summary) are what you are looking for.

The `push` method will add a child to a parent ref, generating push key (a combination of some random data and a timestamp - so that the keys will sort by time). It returns a 'thenable' database ref (i.e. a Promise) from which you can obtain the push key.

You could do something like this:

```
saveToFirebase(bug: MyBugs): Promise<string> {
    const bugsList = this.af.database.list('/bugs');
    const result = bugsList.push(bug);
    return result.then(() => result.key) as Promise<string>;
}
```

it can be called like this:

```
this.formsService
  .saveToFirebase(bug)
  .then((key: string) => console.log('pushed: ' + key))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The above example resolves the promise to the push key, so that it's available to the service's caller.

Comment: Thanks. How would I know if an error occurred in this case?

Comment: Actually, `set` returns `firebase.Promise<void>` which is a little annoying, but it's safe to cast it: `return bugRef.set(bug) as Promise<void>;`

Comment: Stupid question. Why is Promise annoying? It does the job in this case. Also, if you have : Promise<void> , wouldn't it be redundant to cast it as return bugRef.set(bug) as Promise<void>?

Comment: It's not the promise; it's the fact that it's a `firebase.Promise` that is a little annoying - as it's seen, by TypeScript, as a different type to `Promise`. That's all.

Comment: Thanks Cartant. You are correct, I do indeed need the push instead. However, why is it observable? Would I just want to push it to the list once and leave it just like a Promise?. Would you mind sharing how I can change it so that it's done via observable? The documentation is not very clear unfortunately....